# RCPTT failed to launch in eclipse 4.23: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract getModels()' of abstract class LaunchValidationOperation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-rcptt

```
Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract java.util.Set getModels()' of abstract class org.eclipse.pde.internal.launching.launcher.LaunchValidationOperation
```

I am getting this error when I try to run RCPTT on Eclipse 4.23:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract java.util.Set getModels()' of abstract class org.eclipse.pde.internal.launching.launcher.LaunchValidationOperation.
    at org.eclipse.pde.internal.launching.launcher.LaunchValidationOperation.run(LaunchValidationOperation.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.rcptt.launching.internal.target.TargetPlatformHelper.validateBundles(TargetPlatformHelper.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.rcptt.launching.internal.target.TargetPlatformHelper.resolve(TargetPlatformHelper.java:562)
    at org.eclipse.rcptt.launching.configuration.Q7LaunchConfigurationDelegate.preLaunchCheck(Q7LaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:767)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:716)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1021)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$2.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1224)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), having only the first line of the stack trace and not knowing which things of which version are involved here (except the pretty outdated version of Eclipse which is unclear whether you use it to develop your RCP application or it's the Eclipse on which your RCP application is based on), one can only say that something (maybe RCPTT) uses some internal things of PDE which is missing because it is missing in the PDE version you have. In other words, the versions do not work together.

Comment: That method used to exist in LaunchValidationOperation but was removed some time ago. So your versions of RCPTT and Eclipse RCP are not compatible.

Comment: - eclipse 4.23 and rcptt version is 2.5.1 (https://download.eclipse.org/rcptt/release/2.5.1/repository/)

Comment: if I use eclipse 4.18 and rcptt 2.5.1 
then facing this issue -

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Update to static final field org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.ajc$tjp_0 attempted from a different method (ajc$preClinit) than the initializer method <clinit>

Comment: Eclipse 4.23 and RCPTT 2.5.1 were both part of [Eclipse 2022-03](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/2022-03) a year ago. Please tell both versions, the Eclipse version from within you launch RCPTT (or do you launch it in a different way?) and the Eclipse version on which your RCP application is based. You get the error where? In the Eclipse IDE from which you launch your RCP application? Please show the full error as follows: go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: Sorry @howlger!!

So I was trying to run RCPTT AUT from ecliipse 4.23. 

RCPTT plugin I installed from this repo (download.eclipse.org/rcptt/release/2.5.1/repository)

but now it got resolved now. I just upgraded this rcptt 2.5.1 to 2.5.2.  

Thanks for your input and valuable attention!